# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for Kotlin in Visual Studio Code

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code

I want to try out Kotlin in Visual Studio Code. I installed everything new. In Visual Studio Code I installed the Kotlin, Kotlin Language and Code Runner plugins. Furthermore I downloaded a zip file with kontlinc, the Kotlin compiler, since this was not part of the plugins as it seems. Additionally I use Java 11. My path variables are configured. Now when I try to run a simple test

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   println("Hello World!")
}
```

I get the following error.

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Matthias\Desktop\Kotlin\" && kotlinc test.kt -include-runtime -d test.jar && 
java -jar test.jar
exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10939 out of bounds for length 10939
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUnsignedShort(ClassReader.java:2464)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(ClassReader.java:2525)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:761)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:646)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:507)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.modules.JavaModuleInfo$Companion.read(JavaModuleInfo.kt:67)
at 
org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder.findSystemModule(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:44)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder.access$findSystemModule(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:25)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder$systemModules$1.invoke(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:37)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder$systemModules$1.invoke(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:25)
at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:149)
at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:109)
at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:133)
at kotlin.sequences.FlatteningSequence$iterator$1.ensureItemIterator(Sequences.kt:254)
at kotlin.sequences.FlatteningSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:241)
at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.none(_Sequences.kt:1239)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.addModularRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:227)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.computeRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:124)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.convertClasspathRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:79)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:230)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:114)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:409)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:286)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createEnvironmentWithScriptingSupport(K2JVMCompiler.kt:276)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:196)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:109)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:53)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:70)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:36)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:157)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:148)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt:343)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader.run(Preloader.java:81)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader.main(Preloader.java:43)
```

Has anybody an idea where the problem could be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. I used an old complier which I found somewhere, [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.3.50) one can donwload the newest compliler.